# xmllint returns XPath set is empty

Tags: xml, xmllint

What I do wrong?
I get XPath set is empty when run the following command.
`xmllint --xpath './/PackageReference[@Include="Tips"]/Version/text()' sdk/Test/TestSample.xml`

Please find below the xml file content.

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<ItemGroup>
 <PackageReference Include="Tips">
   <Version>2.2.2</Version>
 </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
 <PackageReference Include="Hips">
   <Version>1.1.1</Version>
 </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are getting entangled with the dreaded [namespaces](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp). Since xmllint doesn't support namespace declarations, you can use this:

```
xmllint --xpath "//*[local-name()='PackageReference'][@Include='Tips']/*[local-name()='Version']/text()" your_file.xml
```

Alternatively, you can use xmlstarlet, like this:

```
xml sel -N x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" -t -m "//x:PackageReference[@Include='Tips']/x:Version/text()" -v . your_file.xml
```

They should both output

```
2.2.2
```

Comment: @JackFleeting is that a typo in your second command ? what's the `xml` command ?

Comment: @WestFarmer Not a typo; `xml` is an alias (shortcut) for `xmlstarlet`; you can use either.